# Java - using Swing Timer to do a task every 1/100 seconds

Tags: java, swing, timer

I'm trying to make a counter that counts every 1/100 of a second until the program is closed, but it appears to be a little slower than that.  Here's what I have:

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class counterTest extends JFrame
{
    JLabel label;
    long counter = 0;
    String counterStr;

    public counterTest()
    {
        super("counter");

        ActionListener listener = new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                counter++;
                counterStr = Long.toString(counter);
                label.setText(counterStr);                
            }
        };

        label = new JLabel();

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setSize(100,100);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);

        add(label);

        javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(10, listener);
        timer.setInitialDelay(0);
        timer.start();
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        counterTest c = new counterTest();
        c.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

The "10" in the line where I declare "timer" should cause "listener" to run every 1/100 second, correct?  It seems a bit slower... what is wrong here?

EDIT: Full code posted.

Comment: "seems a bit slower", sounds like you aren't even sure if it is or not

Comment: A Swing Timer is not built to be 100% accurate, and 1/100 may be pushing it's limits. Consider using the Swing Timer but displaying absolute time differences, calculated by getting the time.

Comment: @redFIVE I just tested it with a stopwatch, and my program is indeed slower.  Any idea what I can do to fix it?

Comment: @NickH88 refer to what Hovercraft said, he knows his stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Swing Timer is not built to be 100% accurate, and 1/100 may be pushing it's limits. Consider using the Swing Timer but displaying absolute time differences, calculated by getting the time.

e.g.,

```
private class MyTimerListener implements ActionListener {
    private long startTime = 0;

    public void reset() {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long delta = (time - startTime) / 10L;
        label.setText(String.valueOf(delta));
    }
}
```

OK, my mini-program:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyTimer2 extends JPanel implements GuiTimer {
    private static final String TIME_FORMAT = "%03d:%03d";
    private static final int EXTRA_WIDTH = 50;
    private JLabel timerLabel = new JLabel();
    private TimerControl timerControl = new TimerControl(this);

    public MyTimer2() {
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.add(new JLabel("Time:"));
        topPanel.add(timerLabel);

        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
        centerPanel.add(new JButton(timerControl.getStartAction()));
        centerPanel.add(new JButton(timerControl.getStopAction()));

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setDeltaTime(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void setDeltaTime(int delta) {
        int secs = (int) delta / 1000;
        int mSecs = (int) delta % 1000;
        timerLabel.setText(String.format(TIME_FORMAT, secs, mSecs));
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        Dimension superSz = super.getPreferredSize();
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return superSz;
        }
        int prefW = superSz.width + EXTRA_WIDTH;
        int prefH = superSz.height;
        return new Dimension(prefW, prefH);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        MyTimer2 mainPanel = new MyTimer2();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyTimer2");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}

interface GuiTimer {
    public abstract void setDeltaTime(int delta);
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class TimerControl {
    private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 10;
    private long startTime = 0;
    private long pauseTime = 0;
    private Timer timer;
    private GuiTimer gui;
    private StartAction startAction = new StartAction();
    private StopAction stopAction = new StopAction();

    public TimerControl(GuiTimer gui) {
        this.gui = gui;
    }

    public Action getStopAction() {
        return stopAction;
    }

    public Action getStartAction() {
        return startAction;
    }

    enum State {
        START("Start", KeyEvent.VK_S), 
        PAUSE("Pause", KeyEvent.VK_P);
        private String text;
        private int mnemonic;

        private State(String text, int mnemonic) {
            this.text = text;
            this.mnemonic = mnemonic;
        }

        public String getText() {
            return text;
        }

        public int getMnemonic() {
            return mnemonic;
        }
    };

    private class StartAction extends AbstractAction {
        private State state;

        public StartAction() {
            setState(State.START);
        }

        public final void setState(State state) {
            this.state = state;
            putValue(NAME, state.getText());
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, state.getMnemonic());
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (state == State.START) {
                if (timer != null && timer.isRunning()) {
                    return; // the timer's already running
                }
                setState(State.PAUSE);
                if (startTime <= 0) {
                    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    timer = new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new TimerListener());
                } else {
                    startTime += System.currentTimeMillis() - pauseTime;
                }
                timer.start();
            } else if (state == State.PAUSE) {
                setState(State.START);
                pauseTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                timer.stop();
            }
        }
    }

    private class StopAction extends AbstractAction {
        public StopAction() {
            super("Stop");
            int mnemonic = KeyEvent.VK_T;
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (timer == null) {
                return;
            }
            timer.stop();
            startAction.setState(State.START);
            startTime = 0;
        }
    }

    private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long delta = time - startTime;
            gui.setDeltaTime((int) delta); 
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your code.  The reset method is never called, and is MyTimerListener some kind of built-in class?  It appears light-blue like other built-in classes.

Comment: @NickH88: You would have to call the reset method yourself just before starting the Timer. MyTimerLIstner is just a private inner class that I"ve created that would go into the GUI program. If you create and post your [mcve], I can show you mreo.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I'm essentially trying to make a ghetto stopwatch that displays to the nearest 1/100th of a second since I'm having trouble understanding the code of the sample ones online.  My intention was to change the code to add 10 to the milliseconds portion of a "Duration" object every 1/100th of a second, instead of adding 1 to `counter` every time.  Will your code allow me to do this?

Also, I see it all the time on here, but I do not understand "@Override."  Can this be done without it?

Comment: Okay, MCVE posted in first post.

Comment: @NickH88: and I've posted mine.

Comment: I've been mucking about with another example, which uses `LocalTime` and `Duration` which might reduce some the complexity, but over the rangers we're probably talking about here, this is still acceptable, just found the additional of the `Time` API cut down the modular maths :P

Comment: @Hoverecraft Full Of Eels Thanks so much!  Now, what I'd like to do with it is a bit complicated.  I'd like to have 3 JTextFields.that take in mins, secs, and CENTIseconds (can just x10 to get milliseconds), and a "Submit" button.  While the stopwatch is running, the user can hit "Submit" and cause the timer to immediately begin a countDOWN from those values **starting from the time the stopwatch started**.  For example, if the stopwatch has been running for 20 minutes and the user inputted 25 minutes, a 5-minute countdown would begin.  Any advice on how I might be able to implement this?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Following my above post, I posted a new thread [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33512527/java-updating-existing-stopwatch-code-to-include-countdown) where I edited your code to get closer to my goal, and all that is left to do is to link my ActionEvent method to the "Submit" button, remove "Start" and "Stop", and add the code to count down from a specified milliseconds value.  Could you please take a look at it?  Thanks!

Comment: @NickH88: consider accepting this answer if it answered your initial question (not your new questions).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Okay, done deal.  Correction - I want to keep the Start button, but not Pause/Stop.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Sorry to bug you, but would you mind taking a look at [my new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33512527/java-updating-existing-stopwatch-code-to-include-countdown)?  I'm really stuck with trying to figure out how to implement the countdown.  I have the code that calculates the value that I want to count down from (seen in the commented-out code at the bottom), but that's as far as I was able to get.