# Java - updating existing stopwatch code to include countdown

Tags: java, swing, timer, countdown

@HovercraftFullofEels was kind enough to help me by providing me the basis for the following code, which I made some modifications to (marked by "line completely added" comments and the giant comment at the end, which contains code to be placed somewhere in the file).

The original file was a simple stopwatch, and my modifications are to include 3 JTextFields.that take in mins, secs, and CENTIseconds (1 centisecond = 1/100 of a second).  I want to include a "Submit" button too, which allows the program to read the input of these 3 text fields.  I wrote the code for the method to be invoked when "Submit" is clicked (included in the giant comment at the end).  Upon clicking it, I want the program to immediately begin a countdown from those values **starting from the time the stopwatch started** rather than from the time of clicking the button. For example, if the stopwatch has been running for 20 minutes upon the user clicking "Submit" with an inputted time of 25 minutes, a 5-minute countdown would begin.

If this is still confusing, then all you really need to know is that my method ends with a line that provides a millisecond representation of where I want the countdown to begin, at which point I want the countdown to REPLACE the stopwatch.  I also want to remove the "Pause" and "Stop" buttons, but not the "Start" button (you would think they would be easy to remove, but I removed what I thought was appropriate and received an error when compiling) and replace them with the single "Submit" button.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.Font;                     //line completely added
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyTimer2 extends JPanel implements GuiTimer {
    private static final String TIME_FORMAT = "%02d:%02d:%02d";   //changed from "%03d:%03d"
    private static final int EXTRA_WIDTH = 50;
    private JLabel timerLabel = new JLabel();
    private TimerControl timerControl = new TimerControl(this);

    JTextField minsField, secsField, centisField;     //line completely added - should this be private?
    JLabel colon, period;                             //line completely added - should this be private?

    public MyTimer2() {
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.add(timerLabel);

        timerLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 64));     //line completely added

        minsField = new JTextField("", 2);
        secsField = new JTextField("", 2);
        centisField = new JTextField("", 2);

        colon = new JLabel(":");
        period = new JLabel(".");

        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
        centerPanel.add(minsField);          //line completely added
        centerPanel.add(colon);              //line completely added
        centerPanel.add(secsField);          //line completely added
        centerPanel.add(period);             //line completely added
        centerPanel.add(centisField);        //line completely added

        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();                              //line completely added
        bottomPanel.add(new JButton(timerControl.getStartAction()));    //changed from centerPanel
        bottomPanel.add(new JButton(timerControl.getStopAction()));     //changed from centerPanel

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);   //line completely added

        setDeltaTime(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void setDeltaTime(int delta) {
        int mins = (int) delta / 60000;                                          // line completely added
        int secs = ((int) delta % 60000) / 1000;                                 // %60000 added
        int centis = ((int) delta % 1000) / 10;                                  // / 10 added
        timerLabel.setText(String.format(TIME_FORMAT, mins, secs, centis));      // mins added; mSecs changed to centis
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        Dimension superSz = super.getPreferredSize();
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return superSz;
        }
        int prefW = superSz.width + EXTRA_WIDTH;
        int prefH = superSz.height;
        return new Dimension(prefW, prefH);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        MyTimer2 mainPanel = new MyTimer2();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyTimer2");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  //changed from DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}

interface GuiTimer {
    public abstract void setDeltaTime(int delta);
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class TimerControl {
    private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 10;
    private long startTime = 0;
    private long pauseTime = 0;
    private Timer timer;
    private GuiTimer gui;
    private StartAction startAction = new StartAction();
    private StopAction stopAction = new StopAction();

    public TimerControl(GuiTimer gui) {
        this.gui = gui;
    }

    public Action getStopAction() {
        return stopAction;
    }

    public Action getStartAction() {
        return startAction;
    }

    enum State {
        START("Start", KeyEvent.VK_S), 
        PAUSE("Pause", KeyEvent.VK_P);
        private String text;
        private int mnemonic;

        private State(String text, int mnemonic) {
            this.text = text;
            this.mnemonic = mnemonic;
        }

        public String getText() {
            return text;
        }

        public int getMnemonic() {
            return mnemonic;
        }
    };

    private class StartAction extends AbstractAction {
        private State state;

        public StartAction() {
            setState(State.START);
        }

        public final void setState(State state) {
            this.state = state;
            putValue(NAME, state.getText());
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, state.getMnemonic());
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (state == State.START) {
                if (timer != null && timer.isRunning()) {
                    return; // the timer's already running
                }
                setState(State.PAUSE);
                if (startTime <= 0) {
                    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    timer = new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new TimerListener());
                } else {
                    startTime += System.currentTimeMillis() - pauseTime;
                }
                timer.start();
            } else if (state == State.PAUSE) {
                setState(State.START);
                pauseTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                timer.stop();
            }
        }
    }

    private class StopAction extends AbstractAction {
        public StopAction() {
            super("Stop");
            int mnemonic = KeyEvent.VK_T;
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (timer == null) {
                return;
            }
            timer.stop();
            startAction.setState(State.START);
            startTime = 0;
        }
    }

    private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long delta = time - startTime;
            gui.setDeltaTime((int) delta); 
        }
    }

}

/*not sure where this will go, but this is the code for clicking "Submit"   

   //upon clicking "Submit"...
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
   {      
      String minsStr = minsField.getText();
      String secsStr = secsField.getText();
      String centisStr = centisField.getText();
      int minsInput = Integer.parseInt(minsStr);
      int secsInput = Integer.parseInt(secsStr);
      int centisInput = Integer.parseInt(centisStr);

      long millis = minsInput * 60000 + secsInput * 1000 + centisInput * 10;

      long millisCountdown = millis - delta;   //where "delta" is elapsed milliseconds

      if(millisCountdown < 0)
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog("Invalid time entered.");

      else
          //then immediately change from stopwatch to countdown beginning from millisCountdown and ending at 00:00:00

      minsField.setText("");     //clear minsField
      secsField.setText("");     //clear secsField
      centisField.setText("");   //clear centisField
   }
*/
```

If anyone could help me with this, I would greatly appreciate it.  Unfortunately I don't understand the majority of Hovercraft's code, so I have no clue where to go after what I've already done.

Thank you!

EDIT: Here is the updated version of @MadProgrammer's code:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class StopWatch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new StopWatch();
    }

    public StopWatch() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class TestPane extends JPanel {

        protected static final String TIME_FORMAT = "%02d:%02d.%02d";

        private LocalTime startTime;
        private LocalTime targetTime;

        private JLabel label;
        private JTextField minsField, secsField, centisField;
        private JButton start, submit;

        private Timer timer;

        public TestPane() {
            JPanel topRow = new JPanel();
            JPanel centerRow = new JPanel();
            JPanel bottomRow = new JPanel();

            label = new JLabel(formatDuration(Duration.ofMillis(0)));
            topRow.add(label);

            minsField = new JTextField("", 2);
            secsField = new JTextField("", 2);
            centisField = new JTextField("", 2);
            centerRow.add(minsField);
            centerRow.add(secsField);
            centerRow.add(centisField);

            start = new JButton("Start");
            start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (!timer.isRunning()) {
                        startTime = LocalTime.now();
                        timer.start();
                    }
                }
            });

            bottomRow.add(start);

            submit = new JButton("Submit");
            submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (timer.isRunning()) {
                        timer.stop();

                        Duration runningTime = Duration.between(startTime, LocalTime.now());
                        // Subtract the required amount of time from the duration

                        String minsStr = minsField.getText();
                        String secsStr = secsField.getText();
                        String centisStr = centisField.getText();

                        if(minsStr.matches("\\d+$") && secsStr.matches("\\d+$") && centisStr.matches("\\d+$"))
                        {                       
                           int minsInput = Integer.parseInt(minsStr);
                           int secsInput = Integer.parseInt(secsStr);
                           int centisInput = Integer.parseInt(centisStr);

                           if(minsInput >= 0 && secsInput >= 0 && secsInput < 60 && centisInput >= 0 && centisInput < 100)
                           {

                              long millis = minsInput * 60000 + secsInput * 1000 + centisInput * 10;

                              runningTime = runningTime.minusMillis(millis);

                              timer.start();

                              // No negative times
                              if (runningTime.toMillis() > 0)
                              {
                                  // When the timer is to end...
                                  targetTime = LocalTime.now().plus(runningTime);
                              }

                              else
                              {
                                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid time entered.");
                              }
                           }

                           else
                           {
                              timer.start();
                              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid time entered.");
                           }
                        }

                        else
                        {
                           timer.start();
                           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid time entered.");
                        }

                        minsField.setText("");
                        secsField.setText("");
                        centisField.setText("");
                    }
                }
            });

            bottomRow.add(submit);

            timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (targetTime != null) {
                        Duration duration = Duration.between(LocalTime.now(), targetTime);
                        if (duration.toMillis() <= 0) {
                            duration = Duration.ofMillis(0);
                            timer.stop();
                            targetTime = null;
                        }
                        label.setText(formatDuration(duration));
                    } else {
                        // Count up...
                        Duration duration = Duration.between(startTime, LocalTime.now());
                        label.setText(formatDuration(duration));
                    }
                }
            });

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            label.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 64));

            add(topRow, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
            add(centerRow, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            add(bottomRow, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        }

        protected String formatDuration(Duration duration) {
            long mins = duration.toMinutes();
            duration = duration.minusMinutes(mins);
            long seconds = duration.toMillis() / 1000;
            duration = duration.minusSeconds(seconds);
            long centis = duration.toMillis() / 10;

            return String.format(TIME_FORMAT, mins, seconds, centis);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to know two things, the amount of time you want to count down from and the time you started.  From this you can calculate the amount of remaining time

Comment: I have both - "millis" is the time I want to count down from, and "delta" is the time elapsed since I started.  It's all in the bottom part of the code on the page.  I just have absolutely no clue how to implement the countdown into the existing code.  I was hoping @Hovercraft Full of Eels could shed some light on it.

Comment: So you will either know how long the timer needs to run for (5 minutes) or the point in time (135pm).  You need to then calculate the difference between how long the timer has been running compared to that target, which becomes your current "count time"

Comment: Yep, it's all in my code that I commented out in the bottom.  "delta" is the length of time that the timer has been running in milliseconds, and "millisCountdown" = target time a.ka. "millis" minus "delta."

Answer (score 2):

This makes use of the new Java 8 Time API to simplify the process, allowing your to calculate durations between two points in time as well as arithmetic

See [Date and Time Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/datetime.html)

[image]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class StopWatch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new StopWatch();
    }

    public StopWatch() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class TestPane extends JPanel {

        protected static final String TIME_FORMAT = "%02dh %02dm %02ds";

        private LocalTime startTime;
        private LocalTime targetTime;

        private JLabel label;
        private JButton start;

        private Timer timer;

        public TestPane() {
            label = new JLabel(formatDuration(Duration.ofMillis(0)));

            start = new JButton("Start");
            start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (timer.isRunning()) {
                        timer.stop();

                        Duration runningTime = Duration.between(startTime, LocalTime.now());
                        // Subtract the required amount of time from the duration
                        runningTime = runningTime.minusSeconds(5);

                        // No negative times
                        if (runningTime.toMillis() > 0) {
                            // When the timer is to end...
                            targetTime = LocalTime.now().plus(runningTime);
                            timer.start();
                        }
                    } else {
                        startTime = LocalTime.now();
                        timer.start();
                    }
                }
            });

            timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (targetTime != null) {
                        Duration duration = Duration.between(LocalTime.now(), targetTime);
                        if (duration.toMillis() <= 0) {
                            duration = Duration.ofMillis(0);
                            timer.stop();
                            targetTime = null;
                        }
                        label.setText(formatDuration(duration));
                    } else {
                        // Count up...
                        Duration duration = Duration.between(startTime, LocalTime.now());
                        label.setText(formatDuration(duration));
                    }
                }
            });

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

            add(label, gbc);
            add(start, gbc);

        }

        protected String formatDuration(Duration duration) {
            long hours = duration.toHours();
            duration = duration.minusHours(hours);
            long mins = duration.toMinutes();
            duration = duration.minusMinutes(mins);
            long seconds = duration.toMillis() / 1000;

            return String.format(TIME_FORMAT, hours, mins, seconds);
        }

    }

}
```

> I also want to remove the "Pause" and "Stop" buttons (you would think they would be easy to remove, but I removed what I thought was appropriate and received an error when compiling) and replace them with the single "Submit" button.

Take a look at [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) for more details

> Unfortunately I don't understand the majority of Hovercraft's code

And any other solution we provide you will have the same result.  You need to break down you requirements into manageable chunks, work out how the timer moves forward, then work out how you can make it move backwards, then work out how you can combine the two concepts so you can subtract a target value from the running time and move it backwards.

Comment: Thanks.  I understand most of Swing, but instead of a JButton, he uses what I guess are called KeyEvents for his "Start" / "Stop" buttons.  If they were JButtons, I believe I could remove them easily, but when I remove portions of the code that involve "START" and "PAUSE," I get errors upon compiling.

Comment: Nope, he's using `Action`s -> [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html).  Also `bottomPanel.add(new JButton(timerControl.getStartAction())); ` <- is using `JButton`s

Comment: Is the program you posted supposed to mimic what the GIF you posted does?  It doesn't seem to do anything for me.

Comment: The GIF is a screen recording of the program running.  Seems to work fine for me

Comment: Okay, I got it working now.  Not sure why it wasn't responsive before.  So I can simply replace the `runningTime = runningTime.minusSeconds(8);` line with `runningTime = runningTime.minusMillis(x);`, where "x" is the value I calculated of inputted time minus elapsed time (assuming I create and set up JTextFields and a corresponding ActionListener for my input time)?

Comment: Essentially, yes, although you might want to use `minusMinutes` instead, and the value will obviously need to be a `long`

Comment: Right, "x" would be a long.  Only problem is that I need to keep track of time to the nearest 1/100 of a second, and upon adding a "centiseconds" feature, I see that your program appears to only update twice a second.  Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Increase the frequency at which the timer triggers and update -> `timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {`

Comment: Okay, I've edited the original question to include my updated version of your program.  There's 2 things left I'd like to do to it: I'd like to change the layout of the GUI to where the 3 JTextFields are side-by-side horizontally and the 2 JButtons are side-by-side horizontally (on a separate row than the JButtons), and I'd like to print the "Invalid time entered" error if someone enters anything other than a number in the JTextFields.  Any advice on this?  If there's anything else you think I can do to clean up my code, please let me know.

Comment: [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), [Validating Input](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification), [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter), [How to Use Spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html), [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html)

Comment: Thanks for the links.  I changed to a BorderLayout and I actually ran across a nifty trick for checking if a string is a number or not: stringName.matches("\\d+$") or stringName.matches("^-\\d+$"), the latter of which allows the negative sign, which I would not want in this program.  If you see anything that can be cleaned up (especially with the frequently used line `timer.start();`, please let me know.  Otherwise, I have exactly what I want!  Thank you! :)