# I am trying to make a simple box clicking game with java and im stuck

Tags: java, time, jframe

I am making a box clicking game where I want the box to have a random shape and position on a 500x500 JFrame. Also, I want to add a minute timer so that the game ends after that minute has expired.

**Here is my code:**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.\*;

public class Main {

    int boxSize;
    int boxPosY;
    int boxPosX;
    int points = 0;
    boolean isLooping = false;

    public static void main(String\[\] args) {
        // A JFrame is a window where we can design our UI
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Game");
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setLayout(null);

        // create a Button and a Label
        JButton startButton = new JButton("Click to start");
        JButton pointButton = new JButton("");
        pointButton.setVisible(false);
        JLabel pointLabel = new JLabel();

        // place and size for components
        // setBounds(x position, y position, width, height)
        startButton.setBounds(175, 200, 150, 50);
        pointButton.setBounds(100, 100, 100, 100);
        pointLabel.setBounds(0,0,200,50);
        pointLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 32));
        pointLabel.setForeground(Color.BLUE);

        // add components to JFrame f
        frame.add(startButton);
        frame.add(pointButton);
        frame.add(pointLabel);

        // add event listener for button click

        startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                pointButton.setVisible(true);
                startButton.setVisible(false);
                final int points = 0;
                pointLabel.setText("Points: " + points);  
            }
        });

        while (true) {
            pointButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    final int points = 0 + 1;
                    pointLabel.setText("Points: " + points);
                } 
            });
            break; // here to just break out of the loop not finished.
        }

        // make the frame visible
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void randomiz() {
        boxSize = (int)(Math.random() \* 100) + 1;
        boxPosY = (int)(Math.random() \* 500) + 1;
        boxPosX = (int)(Math.random() \* 500) + 1;
    }
}
```

I want to make a simple box clicking game but when I click on a box, I want to generate and place a new random box with my `randomiz()` method in my `actionPerformed` method. How do I fix this, also, how do i make a one minute timer to stop the game after one minute has expired.

Comment: This package for managing `Area`s (and doing other things with shapes) could be useful for you: https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/shape/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another example which utilizes a [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to provide Game Duration and Time Remaining display:

## Runnable example:

Be sure to read the comments in code:

[image]

```
public class ClickBox {

    /* Swing components declared a class members for so
       that they can be accessed class globlly:    */
    private javax.swing.JFrame frame;
    private javax.swing.JButton startButton;
    private javax.swing.JLabel pointLabel;

    private int boxWidth;
    private int boxHeight;
    private int boxPosY;
    private int boxPosX;
    private int points = 0;
    private javax.swing.Timer timer;
    private final int timeLimit = 60;  // Game time limit In seconds
    private int secondsRemaining = (timeLimit + 1); // Keeps track of seconds remaining:
    private int titleBarHeight;

    // Constructor:
    public ClickBox() {
        // Create Game Window:
        initializeForm();

        /* Add a Mouse Lister to JFrame to catch the MouseClick event
           in the case where the player misses clicking on a box. If
           he/she misses a box, then a point is removed:        */
        frame.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
                if (timer != null && timer.isRunning()) {
                    points--;
                    pointLabel.setText(String.format("Points: %s%20s", points, "Seconds: " + secondsRemaining));
                }
            }
        });

        /* Add a Window Listener for JFrame to make use of the 
           `windowClosing` event in order to shut down the swing
           timer if it's running and the Window is abruptly closed:  */
        frame.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
                if (timer != null && timer.isRunning()) {
                    timer.stop();
                }
            }
        });
        
        /* Add a JFrame resize event to maintain center for the Points and 
           Seconds Remaining as well as set the location of the Start button 
           in the center of JFrame Window when it is resized.           */
        frame.addComponentListener(new java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentResized(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) {
                java.awt.Component c = (java.awt.Component) evt.getSource();
                pointLabel.setSize(frame.getWidth(), 30);
                startButton.setLocation(((frame.getWidth() / 2) - (150/2)), 
                                       ((frame.getHeight() / 2) - (30/2)) - 
                                       (titleBarHeight == 0 ? 35 : titleBarHeight));
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* App started this way to avoid the need for statics
           unless we really want them:        */
        new ClickBox().startGame(args);

    }

    private void startGame(String[] args) {
        // Make the JFrame (Game) Window visible:
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            frame.setVisible(true);
            
            // Center Window in Screen
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
            
            /* Get the JFrame's TitleBar height. This value is used
               in maintaining center for the Game `Start` Button: */
            titleBarHeight = frame.getInsets().top + frame.getInsets().bottom;
        });
    }

    private void initializeForm() {
        // Initialize a JFrame Window & set properties:
        frame = new javax.swing.JFrame("Click-Box Game - You have " + timeLimit + " seconds to click on Boxes!");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        frame.setLayout(null);

        // Initialize the Start Button & set properties:
        startButton = new javax.swing.JButton("Click to start");
        // Size and Placement for the Start Button:
        startButton.setSize(150, 30);
        startButton.setLocation(((frame.getWidth() / 2) - (150/2)), 
                               ((frame.getHeight() / 2) - (30/2)) - 20);

        // BOX (which is actually a JButton)
        javax.swing.JButton boxButton = new javax.swing.JButton("");
        boxButton.setVisible(false);
        /* Get & set the random Size and random Location 
           for 'first' box (boxButton JButton). This is
           later radomly continued within the boxButton's 
           MouseClick event:                          */
        randomize();
        boxButton.setSize(boxWidth, boxHeight);
        boxButton.setLocation(boxPosY, boxPosY);

        // Game label for points (score) and seconds remaining display:
        pointLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        pointLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JLabel.CENTER);
        pointLabel.setSize(frame.getWidth(), 30);
        pointLabel.setLocation(0, 0);
        pointLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 32));
        pointLabel.setForeground(java.awt.Color.BLUE);

        // Add components to JFrame:
        frame.add(startButton); // Starts as visible:
        frame.add(boxButton);   // Starts as non-visible:
        frame.add(pointLabel);  // Starts as non-visible:

        // Add an ActionPerformed event for 'Start' button click:
        startButton.addActionListener((java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) -> {
            boxButton.setVisible(true);
            startButton.setVisible(false);
            points = 0;
            
            /* Setup and start the Game (Swing) Timer. The ActionEvent 
               is fired every one second (1000 milliseconds) and the 
               game duration is maintained with the `secondsRemaining`
               counter:                        */
            timer = new javax.swing.Timer(1000, (java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) -> {
                secondsRemaining--;
                if (secondsRemaining <= 0) {
                    timer.stop();
                    pointLabel.setText("Game Over! You have " + points + " points!");
                    boxButton.setVisible(false);
                    startButton.setVisible(true);
                    secondsRemaining = (timeLimit + 1);
                }
                else {
                    pointLabel.setText(String.format("Points: %s%20s", points, "Seconds: " + secondsRemaining));
                }
            });
            timer.setInitialDelay(0); // No Timer Startup Delay:
            timer.start();            // Start the Game Timer:
        });

        // Add an ActionPerformed event for 'BOX' buttons:
        boxButton.addActionListener((java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) -> {
            points++;   // Add a point to the Score:
            // Update the Points Label in Game Window:
            pointLabel.setText(String.format("Points: %s%20s", points, "Seconds: " + secondsRemaining));
            /* Get & set the random Size and random Location 
               for next box (boxButton JButton) to be displayed.  */
            randomize();
            boxButton.setSize(boxWidth, boxHeight);
            boxButton.setLocation(boxPosY, boxPosY);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Generates a new Random Size and Location for the Box (`boxButton`) to 
     * be displayed within the Game Window. Sizes and Locations can change if
     * the Game Window is resized.
     */
    public void randomize() {
        boxWidth = 0;
        boxHeight = 0;
        int maxWidth = (frame.getWidth() - 10);
        int maxHeight = (frame.getHeight() - 10);

        // Create a box that fits in location x and y:
        while ((boxWidth < 10) || ((boxPosX + boxWidth) >= maxWidth)) {
            this.boxPosX = java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(10, maxWidth);
            this.boxWidth = java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(10, maxWidth);
        }

        while ((boxHeight < 10) || ((boxPosY + boxHeight) >= maxHeight)) {
            this.boxPosY = java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(10, maxHeight);
            this.boxHeight = java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(10, maxHeight);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This ...

```
    while (true) {
        pointButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                final int points = 0 + 1;
                pointLabel.setText("Points: " + points);
            } 
        });
        break; // here to just break out of the loop not finished.
    }
```

is a really bad idea.

Swing is an event driven environment, that is, something happens and you respond to it (the `ActionListener` is an example of this).

Swing is also single threaded (and not thread safe) so your `while-loop` runs the risk of blocking the Event Dispatching Thread which would cause your UI to be unresponsive.

Having said that, the `break` statement will cause the loop to exit on the first iteration anyway.

In general, it's just a bad idea.

If I was doing this, I would start with a custom painting route.

See:

- [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html)
- [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)

for more details.

I'd then make use of the `Shape`s API which provides a lot of additional support including simplified painting and hit box detection.

See:

- [2D Graphics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html) and
- [Working with Geometry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/index.html) in particular

for more details.

I'd also make use of Swing `Timer` to manage the "timed" based aspects of the problem.  See [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details.

You will also need to some way to detect when the mouse is clicked, see [How to Write a Mouse Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2Ftutorial%2Fuiswing%2F%2F/events/mouselistener.html) for more details.

## Runnable example...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new MainPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class MainPane extends JPanel {
        private BoxPane boxPane;

        public MainPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            boxPane = new BoxPane();
            add(boxPane);

            JButton btn = new JButton("Start");
            btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (boxPane.isRunning()) {
                        boxPane.stop();
                        btn.setText("Start");
                    } else {
                        boxPane.start();
                        btn.setText("Stop");
                    }
                }
            });

            add(btn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }
    }

    public class BoxPane extends JPanel {
        private Rectangle boxy;
        private Random random = new Random();

        private Timer timer;

        public BoxPane() {
            timer = new Timer(5000, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    randomiseLocation();
                }
            });
            timer.setInitialDelay(0);

            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (boxy == null) {
                        return;
                    }
                    if (!boxy.contains(e.getPoint())) {
                        return;
                    }
                    // Box was clicked
                    randomiseLocation();
                    timer.restart();
                }
            });
        }

        protected void randomiseLocation() {
            int x = random.nextInt(getWidth() - boxy.width);
            int y = random.nextInt(getHeight() - boxy.height);
            boxy.x = x;
            boxy.y = y;
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        public boolean isRunning() {
            return timer.isRunning();
        }

        public void start() {
            boxy = new Rectangle(0, 0, 20, 20);
            randomiseLocation();
            timer.start();
        }

        public void stop() {
            timer.stop();
            boxy = null;
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (boxy == null) {
                return;
            }
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d.fill(boxy);
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g2d.draw(boxy);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }
}
```

But wait, what's missing?  That's right, I'm doing everything for you.  The "one minute timeout" hasn't been implemented, but I've already provided you with the base solution to implement it, the Swing `Timer`.

However, if you want to display a count down clock, that becomes a little more involved.

You'll also want to make use of the [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) API, as this allows you easily (and accurately) calculate the difference between two points in time.

For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48046501/create-a-java-gui-countdown-timer-that-starts-with-user-input/48046786#48046786); [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33512527/java-updating-existing-stopwatch-code-to-include-countdown/33512781#33512781)

You may also want to spend some time researching the [observer pattern](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+observer+pattern), as this will provide you the means for providing feedback to interested parties about different state changing events (fyi: the `ActionListener` is an example of an observer)

Comment: Thank you so much! This will be incredibly useful to me.